# Identification by tail feather

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

I saw the remains of a bird today I did not recognize, and it was pretty mangled so it was hard to describe it. It was about the size of a robin. However, it had a dark brown mottled body like nothing I have ever seen. I have included below a tail feather from the bird which is 5 inches long. I am sure it is not a thrush or a woodcock or a kestrel. So what was it?

Location is Great Bay, Portsmouth, New Hampshire, United States.

[image]

Comment: Alas, I can't answer the question, but I can suggest you check at this link: https://www.fws.gov/lab/featheratlas/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a tail feather (or [retrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_feather#Rectrices)) from an adult male [**eastern whip-poor-will**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_whip-poor-will) (*Antrostomus vociferus*). See right image below (click to zoom):

[image]. [image]

<sup>Source: [USFWS Forensics Laboratory](https://www.fws.gov/lab/featheratlas/feather.php?Bird=EWWI_tail_male)</sup>

Details:

1. The brown, mottled appearance and the size (~12 cm) match that of the OP's specimen.

   - A great resource for exploring bird feathers: https://www.fws.gov/lab/featheratlas/
2. The whip-poor-will's breeding grounds include the OP's location (i.e., New Hampshire), and according to [All About Birds](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Eastern_Whip-poor-will/maps-range) this species could still be present even late in the year ("they seem to leave between early September and late November.").

   [image]

   <sup>Orange is breeding. Source: [All About Birds](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Eastern_Whip-poor-will/maps-range).</sup>
3. The whip-poor-will is a medium sized bird and similar in size to an [American robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_robin).

   - Whip-poor-will: [22-26 cm](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Eastern_Whip-poor-will/id) ;  Robin: [20-28 cm](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/American_Robin/id)

   [image]

   <sup>Eastern whip-poor-will, (c) Paul Cools, source: [inaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/199837-Antrostomus-vociferus)</sup>